# Entity Framework Linq to SQL expression containing LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to translate some T-SQL to an Entity Framework Core lambda expression.  It involves an inner join and a left joing with a where clause.

Here is the working SQL query:

```
SELECT
   AspNetUsers.*, Exclusions.*
FROM
   AspNetUsers
JOIN Exclusions ON
   AspNetUsers.FirstName = Exclusions.FirstName
   AND AspNetUsers.LastName = Exclusions.LastName
LEFT JOIN  ExclusionsMatches ON
   ExclusionsMatches.RowHash = Exclusions.RowHash
WHERE
   ExclusionsMatches.MatchIgnoredByUserId IS NULL
```

Which I have thus far translated into LINQ lambda as such:

```
var result = _db.Users
.Join(_db.Exclusions, usr => new { usr.FirstName, usr.LastName }, Exc => new { Exc.FirstName, Exc.LastName }, (usr, Exc) => new { usr, Exc })
.GroupJoin(_db.ExclusionsMatches, i => i.Exc.RowHash, x => x.RowHash, (i, ExcMatch) => new { User = i.usr, Exc = i.Exc, ExcMatch = ExcMatch })
.SelectMany(temp => temp.ExcMatch.DefaultIfEmpty(), (temp, p) => new { User = temp.User, Exc = temp.Exc, ExcMatch = temp.ExcMatch})
```

This seems to give me the desired query output, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the `WHERE ExclusionsMatches.MatchIgnoredByUserId IS NULL` clause translated.

Any thoughts on how the WHERE might be achieved? I'm also open to changing from lambda expression to linq query expression.

Thanks!

Comment: Word of advice: **Linq-to-SQL** has a separate ORM built by the C# team @Microsoft to showcase the power of Linq - it is **different** and has **nothing to do** with Entity Framework ! Don't mix those two separate product names - you are probably talking about **Linq-to-Entities** - Linq running against entities provided by Entity Framework .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using LINQ is more readable so I can provide an answer using LINQ as below.

```
from user in  _db.Users
join excl in _db.Exclusions on new { usr.FirstName , usr.LastName} equals {excl.FirstName , excl.LastName}
join exclMtch in _db.ExclusionsMatches on excl.RowHash equals exclMtch.RowHash into grp
from itm in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where itm.MatchIgnoredByUserId == null
select new {
    user,
    excl
}
```

Otherwise, if you insist on using Lambda, first you have to select the field in your final selects and then add the needed `where` **in the end** of query.

```
var result = _db.Users
.Join(_db.Exclusions, usr => new { usr.FirstName, usr.LastName }, Exc => new { Exc.FirstName, Exc.LastName }, (usr, Exc) => new { usr, Exc })
.GroupJoin(_db.ExclusionsMatches, i => i.Exc.RowHash, x => x.RowHash, (i, ExcMatch) => new { User = i.usr, Exc = i.Exc, ExcMatch = ExcMatch MatchIgnoredByUserId = i.MatchIgnoredByUserId })
.SelectMany(temp => temp.ExcMatch.DefaultIfEmpty(), (temp, p) => new { User = temp.User, Exc = temp.Exc, ExcMatch = temp.ExcMatch, MatchIgnoredByUserId= temp.MatchIgnoredByUserId  })
.Where(q => q.MatchIgnoredByUserId  == null )
```

Do not forget to track your query in SQL Profiler :)

Comment: The LINQ statement produces two inner joins.  The second join should be a LEFT JOIN.